# Delete nested subdirectories by name on Mac?

Tags: macos, command-line

How can I delete all subdirectories of a certain name via the command line on mac?

Eg if I have

```
/parent/foo
/parent/child/foo
/parent/child/child2/foo
```

How can I run a command from `/parent` that will delete any folder called `foo` and all of it's contense?

Ive tried this command but no luck:

```
find . -type d -name foo -delete
```

Comment: What is the result of running the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `find` you can do:

```
find . -d -type d -name a -exec rm -r {} \;
```

As you have discovered `-delete` does not appear to delete non-empty directories (so its equivalent to `rmdir` not `rm -r`), though this may not be documented.

The `-exec` executes a command, `{}` is replaced by the matching pathname, and `\;` marks the end of the command. So this does a recursive removal of every matching path.

The `-d` sets depth first traversal which means directories are processed *after* their contents. If you omit this `find` will first remove the directory and then try to recurse into it – this results in error messages but still works.

There is a shorter way using `zsh`:

```
rm -r **/a
```

The pattern `**` does a search an matches `a` at any depth.

If `zsh` is not your default shell you can use its `-c` argument to run a command from another shell:

```
zsh -c 'rm -r **/a'
```

HTH

Answer (score -1):

The name of the directory has to be in quotes.
Do the following:

```
find . -type d -name "foo" -delete
```